# Call Webmethod in Usercontrol.cs from Usercontrol.ascx javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls, webmethod

I have a usercontrol and in that I have a javascript function which makes a call to webmethod.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="LeftMenu.ascx.cs"
Inherits="UserControls_LeftMenu" %>

<script type="text/javascript">

function GetRealTimeCount() {
    PageMethods.CountOfMenus('', '', GetCountOfMenus_Success, GetCountOfMenus_Fail);
}
```

My webmethod code is

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string CountOfMenus(string StartDate, string EndDate)
{
    //Code here
}
```

But when I run the code, it gives me javascript error, `CountOfMenus is undefined`. I know the error is because it cant find the method in the current page but I want it to access method in the usercontrol.cs. I cant write the webmethod in every page as I have lots of pages where the usercontrol is used. Is there any way through which I can call the method of usercontrol.cs in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by below method

Javascript :

```
function GetRealTimeCount(StartDate, EndDate) {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "Default.aspx?Method=CountOfMenus&SD=" + StartDate + "&ED=" + EndDate;
    xmlhttp.open("Get", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
    document.getElementById("Count").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
}
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["Method"] == "CountOfMenus")
        {
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            GetCount(Request.QueryString["SD"], Request.QueryString["ED"]);
        }
    }

    private void GetCount(string StartDate, string EndDate)
    {
        Response.Clear();

        // Code to get count

        Response.Write(Count.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
```

The below link from where I got these solutions has many other options to call C# methods from javascript

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/01/Call-Server-Side-function-from-JavaScript-in-ASP-NET.html

Answer (score 1):

when your JS code calls a PageMethod using "PageMethods." , the call does not reach the page method if it was defined in the control. The page methods in the page are only callable.

I suggest another approach, using Http Handler which is also efficient.
Try follow this post:

[Call HttpHandler from javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008362/call-httphandler-from-javascript)

Also, the following post might be useful:

http://www.undisciplinedbytes.com/2010/03/ajax-call-using-an-asp-net-http-handler/

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ScriptManager in your UserControl Page?
if not you have to add it and set `EnablePageMethods="true"`

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: I have a scriptmanager in all of my pages where the usercontrol is called. So if I add a scriptmanager in usercontrol, it gives me error, `Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.`

Comment: and in the pages where you use the user control did you set the enablePageMethod to true?

Comment: yes I have, there are many other webmethods which get called on the pages and they work, but I want this method to be called from Usercontrol's cs page